# how to assign name to count got from apache pig script?

Tags: apache-pig

```
students = LOAD 'hdfs://localhost:9000/pig_data/students.txt' USING PigStorage(',')
   as (id:int, firstname:chararray, lastname:chararray, phone:chararray, city:chararray, cgpa:int);
group_all = Group students All;
student_count = foreach group_all  Generate COUNT(students.cgpa);
Dump student_count;
```

This is the simple program to get count of the students. How can i get variable name beside count like anyvariablenamestudentcountvalue

Answer (score 0):

```
DUMP 'value',student_count.$0;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you dump you should see the name of the column, it will be something like _c0

If you want to rename, you could define a new variable, something like this:

`student_count_named= foreach student_count generate $0 as a, $1 as b`

You could also try to put an as directly after the count, but have not tried that.